# Input vazio após submeter formulário

Tags: javascript, node.js, express.js, passport-js

Olá, estou desenvolvendo um sistema de login, mas gostaria de melhorar algo.
Quando vou cadastrar um usuário, e digito seu nome, endereço, etc, e faço a requisição do formulário, ele devolve todos os inputs vazios.
Como no GIF abaixo...
[image]

Perceba no GIF acima que após eu apertar em **Registrar**, os **inputs ficam em branco**. Esse seria o ponto. **Não quero que os inputs fiquem vazios.**

Bom, abaixo segue o trecho do código que utilizei. Uso o Passport.js para autenticar o usuário.

```
    passport.use('local.signup', new localStrategy({
       usernameField: 'email',
       passwordField: 'password',
       passReqToCallback: true
    }, function(req, email, password, done){
       req.checkBody('email', 'E-mail inválido').notEmpty().isEmail();
       req.checkBody('password', 'Insira uma senha').notEmpty();
       req.checkBody('password', 'Senha inválida').isLength({ min: 5 }).withMessage('Senha deve ter no mínimo 5 caracteres').equals(req.body.password1).withMessage('Senhas não conferem');

    var errors = req.validationErrors();

    if(errors) {
        var messages = [];
        errors.forEach(function(error){
            messages.push(error.msg);
        });
        return done(null, false, req.flash('error', messages));
    }

    User.findOne({'email': email}, function(err, user){
        if(err) {
            return done(err);
        }
        if(user) {
            return done(null, false, {message: 'Email já está sendo usado!'});
        }
        var newUser = new User();
            newUser.email = email;
            newUser.password = newUser.encryptPassword(password);
            newUser.save(function(err, result){
                if(err) {
                    return done(err);
                }
                return done(null, newUser);
            });
    });
}));
```

Comment: Já tive essa duvida, você trata a diferença de senha no lado do servidor certo, uma saída é tratar essa diferença no lado do cliente com javascript usando evento de click ou algo similar. Outra saída é tratar a diferença no servidor mas enviar o dados de volta ao pagina e trabalhar a inserção desses dados com `if()`.

Comment: Este botão "registrar" por acaso seria `type='submit'` ?
Poste seu html e javascript também por favor.

Comment: Isso, exatamente. Ele é um formulário comum em HTML. Já coloco no código aqui.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Poderiamos, ao renderizar a página, enviar um objeto que através de de um script dentro da *engine* de *view*, verificar se existem valores e os preenche no campo equivalente. Assim ao submeter o formulário e retornar o erro, os inputs ficariam preenchidos com os valores deste objeto.

Por exemplo:

```js
if (errors) {
  let valoresInput = {
    nome: req.body.nome,
    email: req.body.email
  };

  res.render('admin/form_add_noticia.ejs', { 
    showErrors: errors,  // enviamos os erros
    field: valoresInput  // informamos os campos preenchidos
  });

  return;
}
```

Logo, no seu formulário HTML, com este código enviando pela view engine EJS, verifico e preenchos os campos do input com objeto `field` que contém os valores armazenados no momento que foi submetido o formulário.

```html
<form action="/admin/login" method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="nome" value="<%= field.nome %>">
  <br>
  <input type="email" name="email" value="<%= field.email %>">
</form>
```

Observe:

- `<%= field.nome %>` para o input do `nome`;
- `<%= field.email %>` para o input do `email`.

Onde `<%= %>` representa um script da engine EJS que irá imprimir um valor neste campo.

Resumindo, voçê tem que enviar o `body` da requisição de volta e preencher os campos automaticamente evitando assim que estes fiquem vazios.